# C#: Selectively clear one bit in a byte

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I want to clear e.g. the 7<sup>th</sup> bit in a given byte `b` in C#, so I try

```
b &= ~(1 << 6);
```

This results in the error `Constant value '-65' cannot be converted to byte` What is going on?

Comment: @Igor: Could you elaborate on why my question is an exact duplicate, because I don't quite see it. In particular, I don't see an answer to my question in the answer of the question cited by you.

Comment: The reason for the error: The left side of your assignment, `~(1 << 6)`, evaluates to a value that falls outside the allowable range of `byte` (which is 0-255). You would get the same error if you did `byte b = -65;`.

Comment: You may have to write ``b &= ~((byte)1 << 6)``. If you need it often, write a helper method.

Comment: Part of the problem is there are no bitwise operators defined for `byte`. All those operators are for `int` (and `long`). So when you do, for example `b & c` or `b >> c`, where both b and c are bytes - they are both promoted to `int`, because that's for which those operators are defined. And so result is also always an `int`. For that reason solution from the above comment (casting 1 to byte) will not help, because whole expression is still an int.

Comment: @dumetrulo: This just gives the same error.

Comment: @Igor: `b -= (1 << 6)` works. Why did you delete your comment.

Comment: You have to do something like `b &= unchecked((byte)~(1 >> 6));`. Yeah, I know it's ugly. Otherwise, you need to make that expression non compile-time constant. For example `int shift = 6; b &= (byte)~(1 << shift)`.

Comment: @chessweb it only works if the bit is set, if it is not set then you get an unexpected result. That is why I deleted it.

Comment: @Evk - do you want to reopen so you can post that as an answer? If you believe it is a better fit than the 2 duplicates let me know.

Comment: @Igor no I think your duplicates are perfectly fine.